# how to get value from label on didselect tableview and store it in array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm having a tableview cell with a label, i need to get the values from the labels when the user click on each cell and store it into array according to the indexpath of tableview.

Comment: Don't get values from the **view** (the cell), get it from the **model** (the data source array)

Comment: Save the data from your datasource array, use the delegate method to detect selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @vadian comment: 
You should access your data model array with the [indexPath.row] value and extract the current value of the data there. Don't access the cell directly.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4, you can do this

Let YOUR_ARRAY be your string array used to populate Table View, then

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print(YOUR_ARRAY[indexPath.row])

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Get Value from didSelectRowAt

*Using cellForRow(at: <#T##IndexPath#>) function it will return a UITableViewCell in  selected row.*

if you used custom XIB tableview cell means downcast that tableview cell  else you can directly access a cell property(label).